# Exclude a member for MDX forecasting using linear regression

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx, linear-regression, forecasting

I want to forecast measure value for the next month using data from **complete** previous months.

For example in this moment September 11, I have to forecast the value of the September month (cause the September month is not over) based on January-August values.

I am using MDX function LinRegPoint with the hierarchy detailed below

> - DimTime
>
>   - Hierarchy Time
>
>     - Year
>     - Quarter
>     - Month

This is the query I been trying without success:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Trend] AS 
    LinRegPoint
    (
      Rank
      (
        [Time].[Hierarchy Time].CurrentMember
       ,[Time].[Hierarchy Time].CurrentMember.Level.MEMBERS
      )
     ,Descendants
      (
        [Time].[Hierarchy Time].[2015]
       ,[Time].[Hierarchy Time].CurrentMember.Level
      )
     ,[Measures].[Quality]
     ,Rank
      (
        [Time].[Hierarchy Time]
       ,[Time].[Hierarchy Time].Level.MEMBERS
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Quality]
   ,[Measures].[Trend]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,Descendants
  (
    [Time].[Hierarchy Time].[2015]
   ,[Time].[Hierarchy Time].[Month]
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Cube];
```

The above query return all month forecasted values to today date including the September month, however It forecasts the September value taking the real values from January to September current date. I need the LinRegPoint function just takes the previous complete months in this case January to August.

[image]

Note the query returns a forecasted value for 9 month (September) but it is using the real value to calculate it. It would result in a misunderstood line as shown in the below images.

This image shows the drawn line taking the previous full-month (1-8):
[image]

Note the positive slope line.

This image shows the drawn line taking all months (1-9)
[image]

Note the negative slope line.

**Question:**
How can I exclude the no complete current month from real values but allowing the forecasted value be calculated.

**EDIT:**
The set should be changing to exclude the last month member in real values but calculating the forecasted value for it.

Thanks for considering my question.

**SOLUTION:**

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Trend] AS 
  LinRegPoint
  (
    Rank(
        [Time].[Hierarchy Time].CurrentMember
       ,[Time].[Hierarchy Time].CurrentMember.Level.MEMBERS
        )
    ,Descendants
    (
        [Time].[Hierarchy Time].[2015]
       ,[Time].[Hierarchy Time].CurrentMember.Level
    )
    ,[Measures].[QltyNoCurrentVal]
    ,Rank(
        [Time].[Hierarchy Time]
       ,[Time].[Hierarchy Time].Level.MEMBERS)
    ),FORMAT_STRING='Standard' //Formating
MEMBER [Measures].[QltyNoCurrentVal] AS 
    IIF(
        [Time].[Hierarchy Time].CurrentMember is [Time].[Hierarchy Time].[2015].[3].[9]
       , NULL
       , [Measures].[Quality]
    ),FORMAT_STRING='Standard' //Formating
select {
    [Measures].[QltyNoCurrentVal]
   ,[Measures].[Trend]} ON COLUMNS
   ,Descendants(
        [Time].[Hierarchy Time].[2015]
       ,[Time].[Hierarchy Time].[Month]
   ) ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly confused which sets in your expression need changing.

I've created a set `[MthsExclSept]` which you should be able to use anywhere in the rest of your script - I've just used it in two places:

```
WITH 
  SET [MthsExclSept] AS 
    SubSet
    (
      Descendants
      (
        [Time].[Hierarchy Time].[2015]
       ,[Time].[Hierarchy Time].[Month]  //<<better to specify the month level
      )
     ,0
     ,
        Descendants
        (
          [Time].[Hierarchy Time].[2015]
         ,[Time].[Hierarchy Time].[Month]  //<<better to specify the month level
        ).Count
      - 1
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Trend] AS 
    LinRegPoint
    (
      Rank
      (
        [Time].[Hierarchy Time].CurrentMember
       ,[MthsExclSept] //<<also added here?
      )
     ,[MthsExclSept]
     ,[Measures].[Quality]
     ,Rank
      (
        [Time].[Hierarchy Time]
       ,[MthsExclSept] //<<also added here?
      )
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[QualityNEW] AS 
    IIF(
        [Time].[Hierarchy Time].CurrentMember is [Time].[Hierarchy Time].[September]
       , NULL
       , [Measures].[Quality]
    )
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[QualityNEW]
   ,[Measures].[Trend]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,[MthsExclSept] ON ROWS
FROM [Cube];
```

The set `[MthsExclSept]` just trims off the last month. Here is a proof via AdvWrks that trims of December from a year:

```
WITH 
  SET [MthsExclSept] AS 
    SubSet
    (
      Descendants
      (
        [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2009]
       ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month]
      )
     ,0
     ,
        Descendants
        (
          [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2009]
         ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month]
        ).Count
      - 1
    ) 
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,[MthsExclSept] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

It returns the following:

[image]

Comment: I've tried your script however it returns nothing. I mean it doesn't return null or error but it doesn't return rows [MthsExclSept] subset you've created. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a statistician - don't you also need to use the new set inside the rank function? (I've editied the answer)

Comment: Now using your edited script I am getting the real values and forecasted values for 1-8 month but not the forecasted value for 9 month. I've done that using Except function before. I am confused with that, I am not sure where I have to exclude the last month (new set) in the LinRegPoint function in order to not use the real value but calculate the forecasted value for it. Thanks

Comment: Maybe don't use `[MthsExclSept] ON ROWS` in your script? Change that section back to how you had it `Descendants
  (
    [Time].[Hierarchy Time].[2015]
   ,[Time].[Hierarchy Time].[Month]
  ) ON ROWS`

Comment: It returns real and forecasting values for the 9 month however the forecasting value is affected by real value of that month resulting in negative slope line as shown initially in my question.

Comment: You will need to change `[Measures].[Quality]` and not include it on ROWS

Comment: That's something I am trying right now. Creating a member that takes [Measures].[Quality] for previous months and get null when  last month be current member then use it in LinRegPoint function and select.